# IOT-HUB device node.js sdk message.on method is not working

Tags: azure-iot-hub

Once the Event will be sent to Cloud IOT-HUB from Device thru Device Node.JS sdk, once message is received on IOT-Hub same needs to be acknowledged to nodejs.
We found couple of reference regarding the same and the below mentioned method should work for the same.

```
client.on('message', function(msg) {
                console.log('Received Message from IoT Hub: ' + msg.data);
                client.complete(msg, printResultFor('completed'));
                // We are done here
            });
```

But this method is not triggering at all in any circumstance.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description of the question and your code lines are inconsistent.

> Once the Event will be sent to Cloud IOT-HUB from Device thru Device
>   Node.JS sdk, once message is received on IOT-Hub same needs to be
>   acknowledged to nodejs.

It is talking about D2C messages received by IoT Hub.

```
client.on('message', function(msg) {
                console.log('Received Message from IoT Hub: ' + msg.data);
                client.complete(msg, printResultFor('completed'));
                // We are done here
            });
```

But it is talking about receiving C2D messages on device client end.

To trigger this method `client.on` you need send a C2D message from IoT Hub server end. For testing purpose, you can simply send a C2D message either from Azure Portal or [IoT Hub Device Explorer tool](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/tools/DeviceExplorer#send):

[image]

[image]

If you run this sample: [simple_sample_device.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/blob/master/device/samples/simple_sample_device.js#L27) you will receive the D2C message like this(I add this line `console.log('client.on triggered!!!');` to the sample code):

[image]

Comment: ok... I got your point.... This is working..                                                                     So, The understanding is, Device SDK client.on() method will call, once message will be sent from C2D path.                                      This is fine..                                           Now, the question is..........  we have to send event thru D2C path using Node JS...... now, how Node.JS will get acknowledge that the event has been reached to Cloud successfully.

Comment: @RamanGupta There is no such acknowledge mechanism. You can monitor the send method if send successfully there will no error occurs. If you want to check the sent messages you can use [Device explorer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/tools/DeviceExplorer#monitor-device-to-cloud-events) or [iothub-explorer](https://github.com/Azure/iothub-explorer#iothub-explorer) to Monitor device-to-cloud events.